# DDD told me that there is no files named like "address"

Tags: c, linker, arm, ddd-debugger

I am training about a bare metal program as refer to one book.
So now, I execute debugging with "ddd" from ".axf" files which is output from "make".

There's something I'd like to ask about this ddd's error.

The picture described below is to be when I command "start".

They say, There are no file named "*0x10210*"

I have no idea but I think some libraries are failed to be called,which is necessary for executing this code.

What could I check for them?

[image]

Comment: There is code by the book writer,"https://github.com/shugaoye/bo/tree/master/c06/c06e1"

Answer (score 0):

I accomplished it by setting

```
target remote localhost:1234
```

before the start.